# MacOSX: how to disable accented characters input

Tags: macos, quotes, diacritics

I'm using Eclipse Juno on MacOSX Lion and have an issue with typing.

I often print one quote/apostrophe and move the caret. But in this Mac version of Eclipse the quote as I type is highlighted by orange marker (it seems like Mac smart quotes feature) and when I move caret - quote disappears. (in Xcode and Appcode everything works ok).

I tried

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled -bool false
```

to disable smart qotes globally, restarted the computer, but this doesn't help.

Also I tried to find in Eclipse preferences something related to "quote", "smart", "correction" but had no luck.

Tried to disable 'Smart insert mode' - useless.

Tried to set `Java -> Typing -> Automatically close -> Strings` to `on` - but now, when I move caret after printing a quote, Eclipse doubles it instead of removing like before. Also annoying. Why on earth in other programs quotes handling works as expected but I can't get it work the same way in Eclipse?

By the way, when I recently pressed quote and then a I got 'ä' symbol. So I assume this is something related to autocorrection.
But even if I disable `Language & Text -> Automatic replacement`, Eclipse replaces <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to <kbd>ä</kbd>.

How to disable this behavior?

Comment: Does anyone know how to turn this off without switching to another input source / keyboard layout?

Comment: See also: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=howtotypeletterswit20100304073426167

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Yes! It's a shame that I didn't know about such a simple thing - but this is because I'm not a mac-maniac, I live on several OSes at once. When I've found out that quote + symbol gives me an accented character I've realized what's happening.

This was very easy:

- Launch System Preferences, open the Language & Text pane.
- Click the Input Sources tab.
- In the list of input methods on the left, scroll down and enable U.S., disable U.S. International.

This 'U.S. International' did all the evil. Some IDE use their own input system, while Eclipse uses common input. 
This feature is one of those 'little convenient things' (just like smart quotes) which turn my life on mac into nightmare sometimes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick for me (using Atom on OSX 10.11)!

Comment: Is there a way, if your only input source is Slovenian language? And these characters still show up despite the fact that the these characters don't even exist in my language but they are still there (the "accented feature still gets triggered).

Comment: On Sierra : System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources

Comment: @JoSmo, have you found a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue with the German keyboard layout…

Comment: @LinusGeffarth not a real solution no. I just press the right arrow key between the two characters. Not perfect but don't know any other way. :/

Comment: @LinusGeffarth no problem, hope it helps. You are welcome. :)

Comment: Man, you just solved the unsolvable. Pycharm on osx was messing up all the quotes and it was because of this. Smashing the up button

Comment: You, sir, are a legend, I've been struggling for weeks with this I can finally code in peace.

Comment: Does not change anything in 12.6 :(

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to disable auto accents for languages other than U.S. English, I made a workaround solution here: [How to prevent the typing of special characters like "~" modifying the next keyboard input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198806/how-to-prevent-the-typing-of-special-characters-like-modifying-the-next-keyb/46202010#46202010)

Comment: This is actually the only option if you use a keyboard layout that is internationalised by design such as Swiss German.

Answer (score 3):

keyboard -> input source -> + -> other -> "Unicode Hex Input"

this will disable the option key for special characters.

I also removed all other input sources to avoid conflicts

Comment: So many thanks to you!!
You saved my day. This is the only solution that works for my Mac mini (Macos Ventura 13.4.1)

Answer (score 2):

It also happens when you're using `ABC - India` layout, simply remove that layout and add the `ABC` one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On my external keyboard to get a backtick I have to press `Alt + \`, however the next character I press removes the backtick and replaces it with an accented character, i.e. typing ` then a gives me à.

If you press Alt+Shift+\ this "auto-accent" behavour does not occur.

Answer (score -3):

You need press 2 keys on keyboard windows + shift and it`s work perfectly.

Comment: Not sure how the "Windows" key is relevant for a question about MacOS.

Comment: Next time please read the question carefully before you answer it. :)

Comment: It might be a Windows key on an external keyboard.