# Visual Studio Code replaces single quote followed by a character to á character

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

For example, when in Visual Studio Code i type single quote (') and then a it gets replaced to á
How to disable this?

Comment: I think you are having a problem with your keyboard, this will happen in Spanish keyboard. What type of keyboard are you using?

Comment: thank you very much for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to damianfabian who gave me the right direction. The problem was with the input source U.S. International under MacOS. Once I removed it and added U.S. everything started to work.

The details can be found in here [MacOSX: how to disable accented characters input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723236/macosx-how-to-disable-accented-characters-input)