# How to add numbers entered by user in Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell

Probably a simple question but I am a beginner
I am using the terminal on Mac
I want to add up numbers entered by the user and print the result on screen

```
#!/bin/sh
echo “please enter the first no”;read a
echo “please enter the second no”; read b
c=$((a+b))
echo “the answer is $c”
```

It asks for the inputs but returns "?? back instead of adding up the numbers
Thanks

Comment: Change to `“` to `"`

Comment: I see no problem with script, i tried it works.. whats your output ?

Comment: If you put a space between `$c` and the `”`, it works.  I'm not quite sure how shell is treating the quote (U+201D, RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK), but it manages not to expand `$c` properly (as wanted).  The moral of the story is "do not use a word processor to edit shell code (or C code, or …)".  Use a U+0022 QUOTATION MARK and not the word processing U+201C (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) and U+201D characters to surround strings.  Or configure your editor not to map the `"` key to the other symbols.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MacOSX: how to disable accented characters input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723236/macosx-how-to-disable-accented-characters-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
#!/bin/sh
echo “please enter the first no”;read a
echo “please enter the second no”; read b
c=$(( a + b ))
echo "the answer is $c"
```

the quotes you have around line 5 need to be " and ", not “ and ”.

Comment: yes the problem was the quotations

Answer (score 1):

The code looks OK, but it could be simplified:

```
read -p "Please enter two numbers: " a b && echo The sum is $((a+b))
```

Sample run (where the user enters *333* and *33333*):

```
Please enter two numbers: 333 33333
The sum is 33666
```